# BubbleSort implemented with do-while loop

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

I am learning basic sorting algorithms. I wrote below but no sure why it never completely sorts it? I thought it would only meet the exit criteria (flag not set to 1) if it iterates over the entire array with no sorting needed.

```
void bubbleSort(int lst[], int size)
{
    int flag; 
    do{
    for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++) 
    {
        flag = 0; //nothing sorted yet 
        int temp = lst[i];
        if(lst[i] > lst[i + 1])
        {
            //swap values  
            int temp = lst[i]; 
            lst[i] = lst[i + 1];
            lst[i+1] = temp; 
            flag = 1; //sort happened set flag 
        }

    }
    }while (flag != 0); 
}
```

Comment: If you are learning C++, then get rid of your "C" style array coding. replace `int lst[]` with something like `std::span<int>` or `std::vector<int>&`.   "C" style arrays as don't have size info .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were almost there. All you need to do is move where you initialize the flag:

```cpp
void bubbleSort(int lst[], int size) {
    int flag;
    do {
        flag = 0; //nothing sorted yet
        for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++) {
            int temp = lst[i];
            if(lst[i] > lst[i + 1]) {
                //swap values
                int temp = lst[i];
                lst[i] = lst[i + 1];
                lst[i+1] = temp;
                flag = 1; //sort happened set flag
            }
        }
    } while (flag != 0);
}
```

If you set `flag` to 0 within the `for` loop, then any time you set `flag` within the `if`, the flag will get reset on the next iteration of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Like the answer fro David, but now in a more C++ style with some coding advices. Like checking your input, using [std::span](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span), [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), [std::swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) and in the output a [range based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <span>
#include <vector>

// never use : using namespace std;

void bubbleSort(std::span<int> values)
{
    //int flag; Use a better name and a boolean type
    // it will make your code more readable
    bool something_got_sorted{ false };

    // never trust your input so validate if sorting can happen
    // your original code would be invalid for an array of size 0 or 1
    if (values.size() < 2) return;

    do
    {
        something_got_sorted = false;

        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < values.size() - 1ul; ++i)
        {
            if (values[i] > values[i + 1ul])
            {
                // C++ has a swap function so use it makes the code more readable too
                // anytime you have to write a comment remove it and make
                // or use a function with a readable name (based on what you would have typed in the comment)
                std::swap(values[i], values[i + 1]);
                something_got_sorted = true;
            }
        }
    } while (something_got_sorted);
}

int main()
{
    // input array (note note a "C" style array)
    std::vector<int> values{ 9,3,5,6,4,2,1,0,8,7 };

    // note size does not have to be passed seperately
    bubbleSort(values);

    for (const auto value : values)
    {
        std::cout << value << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem itself is in its `flag`, which is being initialized at each iteration of the `for` loop.
To fix just move the declaration and initialization of the `flag` variable out of the `do while` loop.

```
void bubbleSort(int lst[], int size) {
    int flag = 0; // Initialize for do loop
    do {
        flag = 0; // Nothing sorted yet
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
            int temp = lst[i];
            if (lst[i] > lst[i + 1]) {
                // swap values
                lst[i] = lst[i + 1];
                lst[i + 1] = temp;
                flag = 1; // Sort happened, set flag
            }
        }
    } while (flag != 0);
}
```